# Get bitmap of the image from browsers

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the bitmap of the image which i am viewing in browser. is it possible to get those bitmap values from any of contentProvider. Pl suggest me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to download on your device the images that you see in your mobile browser, is that correct ?

Comment: yeah, thats correct.

Comment: Then the closest you could do I think is: manually download the image on your device, open it from the Downloads or Gallery app, and share it to your app. our app must have an activity that is accessible via an `action.SEND` intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a crawler to get the web-page contents, like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), then find the image url & either download its bitmap with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library or directly load it into a ImageView (using Glide again).